# SOLID IoC based on configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, interface

I would like to have a collection of connections (REST, gRPC, RabbitMQ) for one or more different types of services. For example, with this configuration:

```yml
connections:
  http:
    - name: connectionA
      host: localhost
      port: 8081
      endpoints:
        - name: employees
          httpMethod: GET
          endpointType: EMPLOYEE
        - name: departments
          httpMethod: POST
          endpointType: DEPARTMENT
  grpc:
    - name: connectionB
      host: localhost
      port: 8084
      disableTls: true
      endpoints:
        - name: employees
          endpointType: EMPLOYEE
```

When using the EmployeeService I would have an EmployeeHttpClient and an EmployeeGrpcClient, as well as a DepartmentHttpClient in the DepartmentService. Those clients would have the concrete implementation using the specific connection details, but the service shouldn't care about that.

What do you think about this approach?

What would be the correct way of doing it in Spring Boot?

Comment: you can use `Factory Design Pattern` for defining multiple connection types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a place where [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) can be used:

> Strategy pattern is a behavioral software design pattern that enables
> selecting an algorithm at runtime. Instead of implementing a single
> algorithm directly, code receives run-time instructions as to which in
> a family of algorithms to use.

Let me show an example via C#. I am sorry I am not Java guy, however I provided comments about how code could look in Java.

We need to have some common behaviour that will be shared across all strategies. In our case, it would be just one `Get()` method from different data providers:

```
public interface IDataProvider
{
    string Get();
}
```

And its concrete implementations. These are exchangeable strategies:

```
public class RabbitMQDataProvider : IDataProvider // implements in Java
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "I am RabbitMQDataProvider";
    }
}

public class RestDataProvider : IDataProvider // implements in Java
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "I am RestDataProvider";
    }
}

public class GrpcDataProvider : IDataProvider // implements in Java
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "I am GrpcDataProvider";
    }
}
```

We need a place where all strategies can be stored. And we should be able to get necessary strategy from this store. So this is a place where simple factory can be used. Simple factory is not [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and not [Abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

```
public enum DataProviderType
{
    RabbitMq, Rest, Grpc
}

public class DataProviderFactory
{
    private Dictionary<DataProviderType, IDataProvider> _dataProviderByType
        = new Dictionary<DataProviderType, IDataProvider>()
        {
            { DataProviderType.RabbitMq, new RabbitMQDataProvider() },
            { DataProviderType.Rest, new RestDataProvider() },
            { DataProviderType.Grpc, new GrpcDataProvider() },
        };

    public IDataProvider GetInstanceByType(DataProviderType dataProviderType) =>
        _dataProviderByType[dataProviderType];
}
```

and then you can get instance of desired storage easier:

```
DataProviderFactory dataProviderFactory = new();
IDataProvider dataProvider = dataProviderFactory
    .GetInstanceByType(DataProviderType.Grpc);
string data = dataProvider.Get();
```

This design is compliant with the [open/closed principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19627/clarify-the-open-closed-principle).

Comment: Beware that [Wikipedia](https://twitter.com/ploeh/status/1175820397306109952) tends to be a poor source for design patterns. In the past it has been filled with misleading and outright false information and examples; and the articles have been routinely edited by non-technical authors.

Comment: @jaco0646  could you recommend, please, authoritative Internet source for design patterns?

Comment: @jaco0646 it looks like there is no web resource which has information about design patterns by Gang of Four

Comment: The only truly authoritative source for the GoF design patterns is the original book itself. If you want to be 100% sure that you're reading what they intended, the only option is to have the book. Every design patterns website I've seen (and there are many) includes at least a few contradictions compared with the book. I happen to like https://refactoring.guru a lot; but I have found mistakes there as well, when compared with the book.

Comment: It's also worth noting the GoF book is not dogma. In several areas, I find the book itself to be extremely poor. So I'm pleasantly surprised to see this answer identify its factory example as neither of the GoF patterns. Where adherence to the book becomes critical is in the simple need to communicate. Whether I adore or despise a particular pattern, we need a common understanding in order to discuss it.